# Significance of file wc.db in SVN

Tags: svn, tfs, winmerge

I am moving some websites from TFS to SVN control. The svn repositories are just on my local machine for now. I may have accidentally put one website into an already existing local repository but I am not sure.

To find out, I checked out the particular website again into a new svn repo via tfs2svn and did a winmerge between it's working directory and the working directory of the repo I may have messed up. The win merge told me that they are exactly the same except for the wc.db binary file in the .svn folder. Since much google searching has not yielded what this file does I have 3 questions:

1) What is the purpose of wc.db? 
2) What information does it store?
3) Most importantly: based on the above answers, if all files in 2 repositories are the same except for this wc.db file, can I or can I not consider the 2 repositories to be identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wc.db and .svn folder inside Working Copy of SVN are internal affairs of SVN. When you compare content, you must not pay attention on `.svn` (or better eliminate it before comparing trees)

> if all files in 2 repositories are the same except for this wc.db file

then they (repositories) are the same at the current state

Comment: Just before I mark this as the answer, does this mean that the history recorded in each repository is the same as well?

Comment: @SOair - In the most general case "the same state != the same history", but in your case (SVN converted from TFS) "yes, 99.9% (not 100%)"

Answer (score 0):

When I compared repositories after migration only wc.db was different. .project file may be different if we select different name for new repository.